# Call c functions from fortran(type enum)

Tags: c, enums, fortran, typedef, fortran-iso-c-binding

Recently,I call c function from fortran with iso_c_binding.But I found some c code.such as:

```
typedef enum
{
    STRUMPACK_FLOAT,
    STRUMPACK_DOUBLE,
    STRUMPACK_FLOATCOMPLEX
} STRUMPACK_PRECISION;

typedef enum
{
    STRUMPACK_MT,
    STRUMPACK_MPI_DIST
} STRUMPACK_INTERFACE;

typedef struct
{
    int solver;
    STRUMPACK_PRECISION precision1;
    STRUMPACK_INTERFACE interface1;
}STRUMPACK_SparseSolver;

int STRUMPACK_init(STRUMPACK_SparseSolver * S,
    STRUMPACK_PRECISION precision1, STRUMPACK_INTERFACE interface1, int verbose)
{
    S->precision1 = precision1;
    S->interface1 = interface1;
    switch (interface1)
    {
        case STRUMPACK_MT:
        {
            switch (precision1)
            {
                case STRUMPACK_FLOAT:
                    printf("srtumpack_float %d\n", verbose);
                    break;
                case STRUMPACK_DOUBLE:
                    printf("srtumpack_double %d\n", verbose);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("ERROR: wrong precision!");
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            printf("ERROR: wrong interface!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know that call this c subfunction with Fortran.because of this structs:

```
typedef enum
{
  STRUMPACK_MT,
  STRUMPACK_MPI_DIST
} STRUMPACK_INTERFACE;
```

I don't know how to solve this problem . I will appreciate any contribution, suggestion about the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Google found me these, searching "fortran iso_c_binding struct": https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Derived-Types-and-struct.html, https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/290051, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info.  Study those, and if you still can't make it work, post a  [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your best FORTRAN attempt.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a structure, but an `enum` (enumeration) supported by ISO binding entity `ENUM`.

In case your binding miss enumerations the following is a workaround.
Enums in C are more or less constant integers which values are assigned by compiler in generally increasing way. You can also force values for each `enum` member using assignment as in:

```
typedef enum
{
  STRUMPACK_FLOAT = 0,
  STRUMPACK_DOUBLE,
  STRUMPACK_FLOATCOMPLEX = 100
} STRUMPACK_PRECISION
```

In this case i.e. we impose to `STRUMPACK_FLOATCOMPLEX` the value 100. We made the same with the first member, in any case the first member have value 0 by default. The second member `STRUMPACK_DOUBLE` will get the value 1 as progressive increment from previous member.
Anyway you can get better info on how `enum` works googling on the net.

In your case the easier way to solve the problem is to convert enums in definitions and using int's as type like in:

```
#define STRUMPACK_FLOAT         0
#define STRUMPACK_DOUBLE        1
#define STRUMPACK_FLOATCOMPLEX  2
typedef int STRUMPACK_PRECISION;

#define STRUMPACK_MT            0
#define STRUMPACK_MPI_DIST      1
typedef int STRUMPACK_INTERFACE;

typedef struct
{
    int solver;
    STRUMPACK_PRECISION precision1;
    STRUMPACK_INTERFACE interface1;
} STRUMPACK_SparseSolver;

int STRUMPACK_init(STRUMPACK_SparseSolver * S, STRUMPACK_PRECISION precision1,
                                        STRUMPACK_INTERFACE interface1, int verbose)
{
    S->precision1 = precision1;
    S->interface1 = interface1;
    switch (interface1)
    {
        case STRUMPACK_MT:
        {
            switch (precision1)
            {
                case STRUMPACK_FLOAT:
                    printf("srtumpack_float %d\n", verbose);
                    break;
                case STRUMPACK_DOUBLE:
                    printf("srtumpack_double %d\n", verbose);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("ERROR: wrong precision!");
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            printf("ERROR: wrong interface!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ISO C binding in Fortran has an ENUM entity.  Why not use it?

Comment: @Steve you're right my answer applies for cases where ENUM is missing (as I supposed to be the case), but I didn't  mention it. I'll  update answer.

Comment: @Steve ISO_C_BINDING has no relevance here. The language does have ENUMs, which are used with BIND(C), but that's not related to the intrinsic module ISO_C_BINDING.

Comment: @Steve Lionel, I could argue that I wrote ISO C Binding without the underscores so I did not refer to the ISO_C_BINDING module, but that's not germane.  I, indeed, as you have done simply meant to bring attention to Fortran's `ENUM` and `BIND(C)`, which permit interoperability.

Comment: @Steve it's a hot button with me, people using the module name to mean the C interoperability features.